# How would you express ''swerving all over the road'' as in a drunk driver?

Tags: vocabulary

他喝醉的时候一直 ...

I know a bendy road is 弯弯曲曲的一条路 but I don't think 弯弯曲曲的开车 can be used.

Then I though about 往左拐 and 往右拐 , maybe I could say 拐来拐去的开车 ?

Comment: In Taiwan, it is called 蛇行.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it graphically describes how one's driving as "swerving all over the road"

- 他喝醉的时候把车开得**像舞龙一般** - he drove **like he was doing a dragon dance** when he's drunk

or

- 他喝醉的时候把车开得**左摇右摆的** - He drove **swinging left and right** when he was drunk

> *maybe I could say 拐来拐去的开车?*

It would work

Answer (score 1):

他的車在"整條路上"(entire road)"搖擺不定"(back and forth swings left and right).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a word for word translation, I think one way to express is:

> 他喝醉了，开着车左冲右撞。